# Do 32 bit apps run slower (on Windows 7) on the 64 bit version than on the 32 bit version?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Assuming a fairly fast CPU (Dual Core 2.9 Ghz) and 4 GB of RAM, will the typical 32 bit app run at :
Faster
Slower
Same speed
on the 64 bit Windows 7 than on the 32 bit version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will run slightly slower as it has to be run through [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) emulation. The difference is probably not significant enough for you to notice, but it is there.

Comment: +1 for short but sweet answer

Answer (score 3):

In fact, some applications may run faster. The system itself will have more efficient drivers. x86-64 requires **no emulation** of 32bit applications, the processor can run 32bit apps natively. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes) actually has a good technical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very contentious and fact-specific issue. There is no one right answer.

No emulation is required for normal code, only on system calls. For most applications, system calls are a miniscule fraction of their resource consumption. So one would expect it to be very, very close to identical in most realistic cases.

If the system has 4GB or more, likely the benefits of the extra memory will outweigh the slight overhead of translating on system calls. 32-bit Windows 7 is limited to about 3.5GB. The extra memory forms a larger disk cache, and disk I/O is more expensive than almost anything else a typical system does.

Comment: Does the OS know to run the 64-bit apps and the OS kernel in the "higher memory" above 4 gb, and leave the base 4 gb for legacy 32-bit apps?  I feel like this would add a performance improvement since it would clear out the bottom 4 gb, meaning the 32-bit apps have more room to work even though they can only access 4gb themselves.

Comment: @dashnick Every application has its own address space, so every legacy 32-bit app has its own base 4GB all to itself on a 64-bit OS.